# Retriving datas till previous month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to retrieve datas from a table till previous month last date.

Sample Code :

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), -1) AS DATE)
```

Its not working, kindly help.

Comment: please show us the query and explain what does `not working` means

Comment: @Squirrel I cant able to retrieve datas till last month

Comment: We can't help you at all if you don't show us the query

Comment: @Squirrel Above is the Query I Used